# Array values optional, or not?

Tags: swift

Could you explain why:

- when I access an array value using array.first it's optional
- when I access from an index value it is not?

Example:

```
var players = ["Alice", "Bob", "Cindy", "Dan"]
let firstPlayer = players.first
print(firstPlayer) // Optional("Alice")
let firstIndex = players[0]
print(firstIndex) // Alice
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of `first` and *index subscription* is different:

- `first` is declared safely: If the array is empty it returns `nil`, otherwise the (optional) object.
- *index subscription* is unsafe for legacy reasons: If the array is empty it throws an out-of-range exception otherwise it returns the (non-optional) object

Answer (score 8):

(The short answers to this question are great, and exactly what you need. I just wanted to go a bit deeper into the why and how this interacts with Swift Collections more generally and the underlying types. If you just want "how should I use this stuff?" read the accepted answer and ignore all this.)

Arrays follow the rules of all Collections. A Collection must implement the following subscript:

```
subscript(position: Self.Index) -> Self.Element { get }
```

So to be a Collection, Array's subscript must accept its Index and unconditionally return an Element. For many kinds of Collections, it is impossible to create an Index that does not exist, but Array uses Int as its Index, so it has to deal with the possibility that you pass an Index that is out of range. In that case, it is impossible to return an Element, and its only option is to fail to return at all. This generally takes the form of crashing the program since it's generally more useful than hanging the program, which is the other option.

(This hides a slight bit of type theory, which is that every function in Swift technically can return "crash," but we don't track that in the type system. It's possible to do that to distinguish between functions that can crash and ones that cannot, but Swift doesn't.)

This should naturally raise the question of why Dictionary doesn't crash when you subscript with a non-existant key. The reason is that Dictionary's Index is not its Key. It has a little-used subscript that provides conformance to Collection (little-used in top-level code, but very commonly used inside of stdlib):

```
subscript(position: Dictionary<Key, Value>.Index) -> Dictionary.Element { get }
```

Array could have done this as well, having an `Array.Index` type that was independent of Int, and making the Int subscript return an Optional. In Swift 1.0, I opened a radar to request exactly that. The team argued that this would make common uses of Array too difficult and that programmers coming to Swift were used to the idea that out-of-range was a programming error (crash). Dictionary, on the other hand, is common to access with non-existant keys, so the Key subscript should be Optional. Several years using Swift has convinced me they were right.

In general you shouldn't subscript arrays unless you got the index from the array (i.e. using `index(where:)`). But many Cocoa patterns make it very natural to subscript (`cellForRow(at:)` being the most famous). Still, in more pure Swift code, subscripting with arbitrary Ints often suggests a design problem.

Instead you should often use Collection methods like `first` and `first(where:)` which return Optionals and generally safer and clearer, and iterate over them using `for-in` loops rather than subscripts.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to use subscript and you don't want to have a crash, you can add this extension to your code:

```
extension Collection {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Iterator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
   }
}
```

and then use it:

```
let array = [0, 1, 2]
let second = array[safe:1] //Optional(1)
let fourth = array[safe:3] //nil instead of crash
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because with `first`, if the Array is empty, the value will be `nil`. That is why it is an optional. If it is not empty, the first element will be returned.

However, with a subscript (or index value), your program will crash with an error

> fatal error: Index out of range

If it is out of range (or is empty) and not return an optional. Else, it will return the element required.

Answer (score 0):

There are default behavior of array property. Array is generic type of Element. When you try to access using first it return as optional.

```
public var first: Element? { get }
```

This is available in Array class.